# JQuery click function preventing ajax request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a simple edit button that should make an AJAX request. When you click this button I have a JQuery function which should scroll the window up to the form as well.

The problem is the JQuery function works but the AJAX call is never made. I know the function is the problem because if I comment it out the AJAX request is made.

```
<div class="panel-footer clearfix">
  <%= link_to 'Edit', user_movie_edit_review_path(review.user, review.movie,review), method: :patch, remote: true, class: 'review-edit btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-left' %>
  <div class="col-sm-1"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-2x"></i></div>
  <div class="col-sm-1"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></i></div>
  <div class="col-sm-1"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-2x"></i></div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $(".review-edit").click(function(e){
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},500);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `return false;` prevents the default action of clicking on the link.

Comment: I'm surprised I thought that would stop executing the javascript code. However,  the ruby also? How so?

Comment: It's stopping the JavaScript code that sends the AJAX request.

Comment: Ruby runs on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your desired function in another place and call it when needed. From what I understood, the function is not yet bound to your element because it doesn't exist in the DOM yet (when it loads), so the JavaScript won't find the element when the document is ready, only when an specific event triggers the creation of the element.

Try setting your function *outside* of `$(document).ready` and bind it to an element in another event that you know will be called *after* the element is actually in the DOM.

Hope this answer helps!

Answer (score 0):

did you try use e.preventDefault()?

```
$(".review-edit").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},500); 
});

or
$(".review-edit").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},500);
})
```

or out of ready() function... I think this is the best solution

```
$(document).ready(function(){...})
$(document).on("click", ".review-edit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},500);
})
```